# Azure Compute Hours

Tags: azure

I would like to host a website on Azure, but do not fully understand how the compute hours relate to it. I would like my website available 24/7, so would this mean 24 compute hours per day?

Thank you very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Comment: I think this should go on superuser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will mean 24 compute hours a day. It means per instance per hour.

Therefore if you have two instances for 24 hours, you'll have 48 compute hours.

One instance for 24 hours is 24 compute hours.

Comment: What if I have a 2 cores VM, is this mean I have double CPU time?

Comment: @WillHuang Correct. Technically it is per core per hour. So a single VM that has 2 cores up for 24 hours a day would be 2 * 24  = 48 compute hours.

Answer (score -1):

Compute hours depends on the amount of resources your website is consuming, i.e. how much traffic it gets ties to the bandwidth used, how much space it takes up ties to the disk space and how much processing power it takes ties to the CPU time.

Check out this calculator to get a better idea of how much it could cost to host your website on Azure - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full

Comment: You do not get charged for CPU time. You do get charged for number of instances deployed per day.  It doesn't matter if your instance is idle or using 100% CPU all day. Same cost.

Comment: Compute hours have nothing to do with traffic / bandwidth / CPU utilization / disk space. Compute hours are the number of hours you're running a virtual machine instance. Small (single core), single instance = 1 Compute Hour per clock hour. Two instances of Medium (2 core)? 4 Compute Hours per clock hour. Runs like that while the virtual machines is deployed.